# Segmentation fault error while trying to expand array with realloc in C

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

My code works well and gives right results up to 3 iterations. However, I got a segmentation fault error after 3 iterations when I trying to run code below:

```
int addNode(double* distNewNode,int placeCount, int* phi,double* lambda)
{
    int i ;
    int nextPlaceCount = placeCount+1;
    //int nodeCount = placeCount -1;

    phi= realloc(phi,nextPlaceCount*sizeof(int));
    lambda = realloc(lambda,nextPlaceCount*sizeof(double)); //This line throws the error

    phi[placeCount] = placeCount;
    lambda[placeCount] = DBL_MAX;
    for (i = 0;i < placeCount; i++)
        if (lambda[i] >= distNewNode[i])
    {
            if (lambda[i] <= distNewNode[phi[i]])
                distNewNode[phi[i]] = lambda[i];
                lambda[i] = distNewNode[i];
                phi[i] = placeCount;
    }
        else if (distNewNode[i] < distNewNode[phi[i]])
            distNewNode[phi[i]] = distNewNode[i];

    for (i = 0;i < placeCount;i++)
        if(lambda[i] >= lambda[phi[i]] )
            phi[i] = placeCount;

    return 1;
}
```

Here is how I called the addNode() function:

```
    int main()
{
    //Create distMat here
    int* phi;
    phi = (int*)malloc(1);
    phi[0] = 1;
    //phi[1] = 1;

    double* lambda;
    lambda = (double*)malloc(1);
    //lambda[0] = 1.2;
    lambda[0] = DBL_MAX;

    int isNodeAdded;

        for (int  placeCount=0; placeCount < 10;placeCount++)
    {
        double* temp =(double*) malloc(placeCount);
        for (int j= 0;j < placeCount ;j++)
        {
            temp[j] = distMat[placeCount][j];

        }
        isNodeAdded = addNode(temp,placeCount,phi,lambda);
        cout << "isNodeAdded: "<<isNodeAdded << endl;
        free(temp);

        for (int i=0;i < placeCount ;i++)
        {
            printf("Node= %d Pi = %d Lambda = %f \n",i,phi[i],lambda[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
isNodeAdded: 1
isNodeAdded: 1
Node= 0 Pi = 1 Lambda = 1.200000 
isNodeAdded: 1
Node= 0 Pi = 1 Lambda = 1.200000 
Node= 1 Pi = 2 Lambda = 3.400000 
isNodeAdded: 1
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Comment: This is not C ! And See [ask]

Comment: main function is C++, but addNode() function is C.

Comment: Unless you compile it with C compiler, it is not! Read the link I provided! And check the results of critical functions!

Comment: Are you aware that `realloc` into `addNode` doesn't modify the pointer in `main` function.....?

Comment: @LPs It changes for the first 3 iterations

Comment: then the answer to my question is:..... No, you are not. @JoachimPileborg's answer gave you what you need do correct your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the argument `phi` *by value*, which means its value is copied into the function local variable `phi`, and as with all local variable `phi` goes out of scope when the function returns and all changes to it inside the function is lost.

If the function `addNode` is in a C source file, then you can't pass *by reference* since it's not supported by C, so you have to emulate it by passing a pointer to the pointer variable, i.e. in the `main` function you need to pass `&phi`, and have the function modified to take `int **phi` instead, with proper dereferencing of the variable as needed.

If, on the other hand, the `addNode` is in a C++ source file, then you can just change the argument to `int *&phi` and you will have a reference variable, which will reference the original variable passed as the argument from the `main` function.

You also have another problem which will give you undefined behavior in the `main` function:

```
phi = (int*)malloc(1);
phi[0] = 1;
```

Here you allocate *one* byte, and use it as an `int` which it typically four bytes.

---

On an unrelated note, you should not reassign the result of `realloc` back to the variable you passed as argument. Think about what happens if `realloc` returns `NULL`. The original pointer is still valid, but if you reassign it you will lose the pointer and thereby have a memory leak.

Comment: I edited that part like this:

`int* phi;

 phi = (int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));

 phi[0] = 1;
`

Comment: If I define it as `int** phi ` then what will `phi[0]` be ? because I can't assign integer anymore

Comment: @Bhoke You have a pointer to the original variable, to access it you need to *dereference* your pointer, as in `(*phi)[0]`. Note, this should only be done **in the `addNode` function**. In the `main` function you should still have a one-level pointer, i.e. `int *phi`.

Comment: @Bhoke Please search for *emulating pass by reference in c* for more details and information.